# Где находится Лысая Гора (по Булгакову)?

Tags: текстология

Где находится Лысая Гора, куда летала Маргарита?
Сообщает ли об этом сам Булгаков?

//-------------------
*Это заготовка для возможного "исследования"*

Пока очень короткий ответ автору белогородской версии (я его уже как-то делал, но теперь найти не могу).

Вор первых приоритеты:
http://pda.sxnarod.com/index.php?showtopic=237846
(2008 г.,  вопросы этой викторины создавались при  моем участии).
Упоминаний о более раннем применении астрономии к анализу булкаговвского теста я не нашел.

//-------------------

Что? Полнолуние - астрономическое явление
Где? В районе Москвы - место наблюдения
Когда - между 21:30 и 23:30 астрономического времени (соответствует 22:00 и 24:00 поясного декретного времени).– момент наблюдения.
Условия наблюдения: примерно на Юго-Юго-Востоке (вытекает из предыдущего),
сначала слева, потом – за спиной.

Таким образом, Маргарита летела сначала на Запад (возможно с небольшим отклонением к Югу), потом – на Север. Эти направления (особенно последнее, обычно замалчиваемое) крепко смущают литературоведов. И им приходится притягивать за уши разные «обоснования», никаким текстом не подкреплённые.

"Маргарита увидела, что она наедине с летящей над нею и слева луною"
"Поворачивая голову вверх и влево, летящая любовалась тем, что луна несется над нею, как сумасшедшая, обратно в Москву, и в то же время странным образом стоит на месте"
"Легкая тень летящей скользила по земле впереди – теперь луна светила в спину Маргарите".

//-------------------

Необходимые пояснения.
В полнолуние луна находится в точке точно противоположной солнцу.
Другими словами в истинную астрономическую полночь луна находится в зените, строго на Юге.
Именно фазой луны (а не временем года, как у Филиппова) определяется направление на неё.
Долгота Москвы -  37°37′00″, 2-я часовая зона по Гринвичу. Истинная астрономическая полночь с учетом принятого тогда декретного времени  (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) наступала в 0:32 пополуночи. Т.е. от астрономического времени отступает примерно на полчаса. Таким образом, во время полёта Маргариты (примерно от половины десятого до половины двенадцатого вечера т.к. бал начался в полночь) луна в Москве находилась примерно на Юго-Юго Востоке - точнее на 120-150 градусах (смещение "на полпятого" - если по аналогии с мишенью). Поскольку Луна была слева, Маргарита двигалась примерно на 220-230 градусов ("на полвосьмого" по мишени). Направление на Киев - почти точно 225 градусов. (На Белгород, кстати -  точно 180 градусов). Какие же города могла видеть Маргарита на этом пути? Калугу. Брянск. Чернигов. Почему их не заметил г-н Филиппов, остается только гадать.

Булгаков фантастически точен в подробностях.

Почему же ближе концу полета луна стала  Светить Маргарите в спину? Здесь есть одна нерешенная загадка, но об этом в следующий раз.

Comment: Помнится, я смотрела по телевизору передачу, там пытались найти место для квартир Мастера, Маргариты, дом Драмлита. Было несколько версий, но ни одна не совпадала полностью с текстом. И это понятно: Булгаков же не с натуры писал, не размечал карту. Может, еще фамилии Мастера и Маргариты указать?  
Пофантазировать, конечно, можно - но однозначного ответа, думается, не будет.

Comment: Булкаков писал не с натуры. Но в его описания (если они есть) все всегда сч точностью до протокола соответствует реальности. Единственное возможное исключение - совхоз "Красный луч" из "Роковых яиц". Но там почти и нет привязки к местности.

Comment: "Лысая гора (по Булгакову)" - это продукт воображения Михаила Булгакова. Следовательно, указанная Лысая гора находится там же, где находится Кудыкина маунт. В свою очередь, Кудыкина маунт находится недалеко от того места, куда "Макар телят не гонял".

Answer (score 3):

Мне думается, что Булгаков не имел в виду какое-то определенное место. А за основу взял, скорее всего, ту самую Лысую гору, что находится в Киеве, тем более, что в Киеве он долго жил и не мог ее не знать.
По крайней мере, нигде в черновиках адрес не указан.

Comment: >Мне думается, что Булгаков не имел в виду какое-то определенное место.  
  
Тогда он не был бы Булгаковым.

>А за основу взял, скорее всего, ту самую Лысую гору, что находится в Киеве,  
В одном Киеве и окрестностях насчитали семь мест, более или менее подходящих. Хотя тут согласен, "какнонизированная" киевлянами Лысая Гора вполне заслуживает этого звания. Но мне хотелось бы вывести это из самого текста.

>По крайней мере, нигде в черновиках адрес не указан.

А зачем нам "черновики", если есть канонический текст?

Ну хорошо, значит некий интерес к теме все же есть. Будет статья.

Comment: Так будет благословение на статью в исследованиях?
Там пока пусто...

Comment: А кто должен его давать? Тема интересная, но несколько трудная для не-астронома. Придется верить автору на слово... Но все равно интересно. Начните, раздел "Исследования" - полезный раздел.

Comment: Никто не должен. Но хотелось модераторского напутствия.
А вот насчет сложности - это интересно. Неужели и Вам так сложно?
Может, рисунками разбавить? Нужно-то всего ниxего: план Москвы и карта европейской части СССР.
**Кстати, если вдруг кто вдруг располагает расписанием поездов "Москва-Киев" за 30 годы - буду всемерно благодарен**.   
И от хорошего плана Москвы 30-х не откажусь, хотя у меня и есть несколько, но не совсем удачных.

Comment: Интересно, зачем было спрашивать, если на каждую фразу ответов у Вас пятьдесят возражений?

Comment: >Интересно, зачем было спрашивать, если на каждую фразу ответов у Вас пятьдесят возражений?  
  
Не понял.

Comment: Пишите, behemotus, пишите!   
"Никогда и ничего не просите! Никогда и ничего, в особенности у тех, кто сильнее вас!"

Answer (score 2):

Версий много, одна из них - В. Филиппова: Вспомним, как Азазелло давал наставления Маргарите: "...Полетайте над городом, чтобы попривыкнуть, и затем на юг, вон из города, и прямо на реку...", Маргарита намазалась кремом, который ей дал Азазелло, в полдесятого вечера. Полёт над городом и разгром квартиры критика Латунского заняли у неё где-то около часа. Значит, вылетела Маргарита из Москвы после десяти вечера. Была середина мая. Ориентиром ей служила луна: "...Маргарита увидела, что она наедине с летящей над нею и слева луною". Но в это время полная луна наблюдается не строго на востоке, а смещена к югу градусов на двадцать. Значит, Маргарита летела на юго-запад, её примерный курс - 200 градусов.
Географические координаты Москвы: 55 градусов 45 минут северной широты (с.ш.) и 37 градусов 37 минут восточной долготы (в.д.). Киев южнее Москвы на 590 км (50 град. 26 мин. с.ш.) и западнее на 788 км (30 град. 31 мин. в.д.). Из Москвы в Киев можно долететь, придерживаясь курса 235 градусов. Поэтому если бы Маргарита летела в Киев, то луна была бы у неё позади - за левым плечом.
И ещё одна важная contra киевской версии. Маргарита несколько раз видела внизу "озёра электрических огней" - это были города. А в месте её приземления была тьма, в которой лишь одиноко "метался огонёчек от костра". Значит, не на киевскую Лысую гору, даже в то время уже неплохо освещённую, прилетела Маргарита.
Курс 200 градусов, которым летела из Москвы Маргарита, привёл меня тоже на Лысую гору, но только у села Головчино в 70 километрах западнее Белгорода. Эта местность на берегу реки Ворсклы удивительным образом совпадает с описанной в романе: "Сосны разошлись, и Маргарита тихо подъехала по воздуху к меловому обрыву. За этим обрывом внизу, в тени, лежала река. Туман висел и цеплялся за кусты внизу вертикального обрыва, а противоположный берег был плоский, низменный...".
И название местности соответствующее - урочище Людоедово. Правда, меловой обрыв почти не виден - склоны Лысой горы покрыты кустами и деревьями. Однако местные старожилы утверждают, что гора всего лет тридцать как густо заросла, а прежде обрыв был "голым".
Виктор Филиппов,
соб. корр. "Известий" -
для "Белгородских известий"

http://belwesti.ru/news-belgorod/bulgakovskaja-margarita-priletala-na-lysuju-goru-v-golovchino

Comment: Людмила, спасибо!
Это именно то, что нужно!
Именно этот астрономический подход (с копирайтами 2007) я собирался развить. Но конечно же г-н Филлипов не прав. "Курс" установлен слишком вольно, с огромной натяжкой.

Answer (score 0):

Я читала в газете Труд 89-90г, там был задан этот вопрос и был получен на него ответ: Белгородская область, п. Ровеньки. Ответ был дан компетентными лицами. Это было написано на последней страничке в рубрике Вопрос - Ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то Маргарита летала не на Лысую Гору. Эта сцена была написана с натуры. Место, где она купалась, – Святогорск. Сейчас Донецкая обл. В общем-то, недалеко от Белгорода. Кстати, сам Булгаков об этом писал.

Comment: Тамара, это, конечно, очень интересно, но абсолютно бездоказательно. Что писал, где пеисал, кому писал? Да и версий таких с разными "адресами" - вагон и маленькая тележка.  Донецк же - вообще неудачное место для таких историй. Там почти нет лесов, все шахтами изрезано. И реки большой нет. Кальмиус не годится, маловат.

Answer (score 0):

Тут снова вспомнили о неком Филиппове с его версией о том, что Маргарита летала куда-то на Северский Донец, а не в Киев.

Вот, пожалуй, наиболее полное изложение взгляда автора, пусть и на форуме сделанное.
http://www.tucson-club.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=7465

Два момента.
Первое. Булгаков никогда не был в тех местах - и просто не мог описать географию (ландшафт в частности) места с такой точностью, на которой основывается Филиппов.
А если посмотреть на карту - так место, о котором говорит Филиппов (Головчино - не "Головчин", он даже название перепутал) вообще далековато от реки, еще дальше - меловая гора. Да и вообще с привязкой к местности - сплошные проколы.

И второе. Полная каша с астрономией. Да, направление на Киев из Москвы  выбрано более или менее верно - 235 градусов (реально - 225). На этом познания Филиппова в астрономии заканчиваются.
Луна в астрономическое полнолуние и астрономическую полночь находится точно на ЮГЕ, а не на СЕВЕРЕ, как полагает Филиппов. На Севере в полночь Луна не бывает в принципе (она просто не видна, так как находится там же, где и Солнце - на противоположной стороне от наблюдателя). То есть ни о каком полете с Луной слева и сзади речь не идет, Луна при полете на Киев будет ВПЕРЕДИ СЛЕВА. Что вполне по тексту Романа
А на Белгород - просто ВПЕРЕДИ. А это уже полная невязка с текстом романа.
Дальнейший разбор версии считаю излишним.

А вот странный разворот Маргариты на Север (в конце полета - Дуна за спиной) действительно слабое место всей Киевской версии.
Я вижу только одно объяснение. При полете по прямой Маргарита пересекла бы Днепр в черте Киева. А там, куда не ткни, - святые места от лавры до Владимирской горки... Нечитьс, понятно стремилась их избегать. Поэтому Днепр Маргарита пересекла ниже по течению, в районе Конча-Заспы, и оттуда уже прямиком вдоль Днепра - на Лысую гору.
Поэтому-то и не было вдоль её пути крупного освещенного города, а котором так переживает Филиппов.